# How to find parent based on node level

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have table tbl_budget with columns id, budget_code and level. Level tell the hierarchy 
  [current table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNJ6q.jpg)

i want to find the parent of each budget code based on its level

this query do find first level parents fine, but not after that

SELECT tb1.id , (Select buget_code From tbl_budget where level = tb1.level-1 LIMIT 0,1) as parent from tbl_budget tb1

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Server version: 10.3.11-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your hierarchy correctly, then you can use `LIKE` to compare budget_codes in the ON clause:

```
select c.*, p.id as parent_id, p.budget_code as parent_budget_code
from tbl_budget c
left join tbl_budget p 
  on  p.level = c.level - 1
  and c.budget_code like concat(p.budget_code, '%')
order by c.id
```

Result:

```
| id  | budget_code | level | parent_id | parent_budget_code |
| --- | ----------- | ----- | --------- | ------------------ |
| 1   | 001         | 1     |           |                    |
| 2   | 001-1       | 2     | 1         | 001                |
| 3   | 001-2       | 2     | 1         | 001                |
| 4   | 001-2-1     | 3     | 3         | 001-2              |
| 5   | 002         | 1     |           |                    |
| 6   | 002-1       | 2     | 5         | 002                |
| 7   | 002-2       | 2     | 5         | 002                |
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iwMtVzNDqHFAGUzNYaF7s6/0)

Another way is to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`:

```
select c.*, p.id as parent_id, p.budget_code as parent_budget_code
from tbl_budget c
left join tbl_budget p 
  on p.budget_code = substring_index(c.budget_code, '-', c.level - 1)
order by c.id
```

If you only need the `budget_code` of the parent, then you don't even need a join, since the parent code is part of the child code, and you only need to extract it:

```
select c.*,
  substring_index(c.budget_code, '-', c.level - 1) as parent
from tbl_budget c
```

Comment: Nice one! Dunno why I didn't think of using the `level` instead of counting dashes :)

Comment: What if the budget code are not like this , mean in order of level? they can be abc , csd ,eff , bla , lab etc ?

Comment: You need some data which can clearly identify the parent row. Usually it is a `parent_id` column which links to the corresponding `id` value of the parent. However - what you have is kind of a "path" (from root node), which is more "powerful".

Comment: @PaulSpiegel if we add group_id to mark one group of levels, will it help is making the query?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following query:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table tbl_budget (
  `id` INT ,
  `budget_code` VARCHAR(255),
  `level` INT
);

INSERT INTO `tbl_budget` VALUES
(1, '001', 1),
(2, '001-1', 2),
(3, '001-2', 2),
(4, '001-2-1', 3),
(5, '002', 1),
(6, '002-1', 2),
(7, '002-2', 2);
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  @count_dash := LENGTH(tb1.budget_code) - LENGTH(REPLACE(tb1.budget_code, '-', '')) as count_dash,  
  tb1.id, 
  tb1.budget_code, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(tb1.budget_code, '-', -1) as child_part,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(tb1.budget_code, '-', @count_dash) as parent_part,
  (
    SELECT id 
    FROM tbl_budget 
    WHERE 
      `level` = tb1.level-1 AND parent_part = `budget_code`
    LIMIT 1
  ) as parent_id
FROM tbl_budget tb1;
```

```
| count_dash | child_part | parent_part | parent_id | id  | budget_code |
| ---------- | ---------- | ----------- | --------- | --- | ----------- |
| 0          | 001        |             |           | 1   | 001         |
| 1          | 1          | 001         | 1         | 2   | 001-1       |
| 1          | 2          | 001         | 1         | 3   | 001-2       |
| 2          | 1          | 001-2       | 3         | 4   | 001-2-1     |
| 0          | 002        |             |           | 5   | 002         |
| 1          | 1          | 002         | 5         | 6   | 002-1       |
| 1          | 2          | 002         | 5         | 7   | 002-2       |
```

### Explanation:

I am assuming that there is naming consistency in your data. The issue is that to get the parent of an entry you dont only need the `level` but also part of the code to be matching

Step 1:

The following counts the number of '-' in the `budget_code`:

```
@count_dash := LENGTH(tb1.budget_code) - LENGTH(REPLACE(tb1.budget_code, '-', ''))
```

Step 2:

Now, we split the `budget_code` by '-' and we return:

- the last part (`-1`) which is the child code
- all the parts but not the last, which is the parent code

This is done using SUBSTRING_INDEX which splits the given string by that character and returns the number of parts requested

Step 3:

Since each code has a parent we join and return the id of the parent. To find the correct one we need the following to be true:

1. The parents' level is equal to our level -1
2. The parents' budget code equals our parent-code part

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pq2SBzFZTTMVfMFthVkDaA/1)

### Method 2

The above shows you how to get the parent code (even without join). However, your query can be simplified to the following:

```
SELECT 
  tb1.id, 
  tb1.budget_code, 
  (
    SELECT id
    FROM tbl_budget 
    WHERE 
      `level` = tb1.level-1 
       AND tb1.budget_code LIKE CONCAT(budget_code, '%')
    LIMIT 1
  ) as parent_id
FROM tbl_budget tb1;
```

In this case we are saying: Find an entry, one level above the current one and whose budget_code is included the current one. Note that you can change parent_id to parent_code, however if code is what is required I would avoid the join

Comment: What if the budget code are not like this , mean in order of level? they can be abc , csd ,eff , bla , lab etc ?

Comment: @IrfanZafar, you have multiple items of level 2 and multiple items of level 1 so how do you plan on mapping those to each other? Instead of going with substrings I would go with a `parent_budget_id` which references the same table. However, if this is missing, I don't see another way of finding out which level-2 maps to which level-1 budget?